# how to check form after postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

Please cosider this scenario:

I have a form with 3 drop down list.I place these controls in an `update panel`.when my users select an Item with value greater that 2 in first drop down list I disable second and third drop down list with jQuery. My problem is after any post back all drop down list are enable.I know this is normal but how I can check the form again and disable controls that should be disable?

### thanks

**Edit 1)**

this is my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="100px">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Width="100px">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Width="100px">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Cause Post Back" Width="200px" 
                    onclick="Button1_Click"/>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        function Disable(item) {
            item.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        $('#DropDownList1').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() > 2) {
                Disable($('#DropDownList2'));
                Disable($('#DropDownList3'));
            }
            else {
                Enable($('#DropDownList2'));
                Enable($('#DropDownList3'));
            }
        }).change();

        function Enable(item) {
            item.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
```

Comment: :(:(:(:( who and for what vote for -1??? this is 1000 times vote down my posts with no reason :(:(:(

Comment: so your questions is, you want to persist the selections after the page is reloaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something?

```
$('#dropdown1').change(function()
{
    if ( $(this).val() > 2 )
    {
        $('#dropdown2, #dropdown3').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#dropdown2, #dropdown3').prop('disabled', false);
    }
})
.change();
```

Comment: Put that in the document.ready or in a script block after the dropdowns and it should do the trick.

Comment: If I write this again,I have this code in 2 place:1- in change event handler,2-in document.ready.Is there any better way?

Comment: @Rozhin - Yes. You can do that by triggering the `change` event on initial page load. See my updated answer.

Comment: Your post + @user1170820 post is ANSWER to may question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to updatepanel, because it is partialy post back your page.
Please put your Jquery inside a  **function pageLoad()**

```
  function pageLoad() { 
    // Put your code here... 
  }
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  AutoPostBack="true"
```

as

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="100px" 
       AutoPostBack="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field, which stores the state of the dropdowns..for example 0=disabled, 1=enabled...when you disable the dropdown set the value of the hidden field as 0..when enabled set it as 1. Then when the form is posted and reloaded, read the value of the hidden fields and enable/disable the dropdowns accordingly.

```
$(function(){

   if($("#hiddenFieldID").val()=="0")
       //disable
   else
      //enable          

});
```

Comment: I think it's easier if I jast call `change` event